# Why are these Xcode search results grayed out?

Tags: xcode

[image: xcode]

I'm referring to the top two and bottom two entries.

Comment: That usually means the text is in a comment, I believe.

Comment: I searched -> @" and it returned all results similar to the ones you are referring to. So its not greyed out but probably means theres @"" involved or something of that sort.

Answer (score 0):

Just having a quick mess around in Xcode it looks like those are showing non executable results like results in comments or plists.

Comment: These results are all .m or .h files.

Comment: Yup I said non executable like **comments** or plists. This could be comments within your code

Comment: Thanks, but they don't happen to be comments.